# Convert Python to R

Tags: python, r

I know there exists a module (rpy and rpy2) to convert R code to Python.

Is there any easy way to do the reverse?

Comment: The rJython package on CRAN and the rPython package on R-Forge let one call Jython code and Python code from R.  The rSymPy package on CRAN uses rJython (and, in fact, rJython was formerly part of rSymPy and since then was factored out into its own package).

Comment: Found a fairly good converter online which converted some complex code python code to R - https://www.javainuse.com/py2r

Answer (score 16, accepted):

rpy(2) does not convert code.  It only allows you an interface to communicate with R from python and issue R commands from within python.

Given that R is very dependent upon statistical libraries that aren't available in python the conversion would generally be a tremendous amount of work.  To convert a single line like

```
lmer (y ~ x1 + x1 + (1|id), mydat)
```

to something in python would take a great deal of work.  If you just want to run that code from python use rpy.  Going the other way, which seems to be more what you are interested in, the conversion could often be a bit more straightforward.  However, the code would tend to be very poorly optimized for R and run very badly.  I recently optimized some R code converted from python by someone who wrote the R code as a more or less direct translation line by line.  The optimization came out 1/3 the length and between 20 and 1000 times faster (depending on the function).

Comment: What does the R code `lmer (y ~ x1 + x1 + (1|id), mydat)` do?  I'm wondering whether this is not the kind of task that NumPy/SciPy would be good at.

Comment: A quick look at the NumPy/SciPy manuals suggests that their statistics support is pretty basic ... `lmer` (in the `lme4` package is for fitting linear mixed models, which is a non-trivial computational problem ...)

Answer (score 5):

John is correct.  These are not converting between languages, but interfacing languages.  Language conversion is not particularly common, though interfacing them is.  However, **object conversion** is quite common, as that is an important part of interfacing languages.

In addition to Rpy and Rpy2, take a look at [RSPython](http://www.omegahat.org/RSPython/).  It also provides for object conversion, and inspired Rpy.

Answer (score 4):

If having Python as a starting point is acceptable, [rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2.html) lets you go both ways between R and Python: you can call Python code while executing R code (doc [here](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.2/html/rinterface.html#calling-python-functions-from-r)).

Answer (score 1):

with PypeR you can go both ways very easily: from R to Python and from Python to R.
http://www.webarray.org/softwares/PypeR/

it works great and this article describes how it works and the advantages over the alternatives (rpy, rpy2 etc.)

http://www.jstatsoft.org/v35/c02/paper

I personally used it to run stat models in R from python, and to import/export dataframes from one way to the other (and convert numpy frames into r-dataframes and viceversa).