# Python to R conversion of a custom function

Tags: python, r, hash, hmac

I have two python functions given below

```
import sys, os, base64, datetime, hashlib, hmac 
def sign(key, msg):
    return hmac.new(key, msg.encode("utf-8"), hashlib.sha256).digest()

def getSignatureKey(key, datestamp, regionName, serviceName):
    kDate = sign(('AWS4' + key).encode('utf-8'), datestamp)
    kRegion = sign(kDate, regionName)
    kService = sign(kRegion, serviceName)
    kSigning = sign(kService, 'aws4_request')
    return kSigning
```

I would like to convert them to R functions

Here is what I tried

```
library(digest)
sign=function(key, msg)
{
  return (digest(hmac(key,enc2utf8(msg),"sha256", raw=F)))
}

getSignatureKey=function(key, datestamp, regionName, serviceName)
{
  kDate = sign(enc2utf8(paste0('AWS4' , key)), datestamp)
kRegion = sign(kDate, regionName)
kService = sign(kRegion, serviceName)
kSigning = sign(kService, 'aws4_request')
return (kSigning)
}
```

Given the following inputs

```
key = 'wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG+bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY'
datestamp = '20120215'
regionName = 'us-east-1'
serviceName = 'iam'
```

The expected output is given below ( As per the python function)

```
kSecret  = '41575334774a616c725855746e46454d492f4b374d44454e472b62507852666943594558414d504c454b4559'
kDate    = '969fbb94feb542b71ede6f87fe4d5fa29c789342b0f407474670f0c2489e0a0d'
kRegion  = '69daa0209cd9c5ff5c8ced464a696fd4252e981430b10e3d3fd8e2f197d7a70c'
kService = 'f72cfd46f26bc4643f06a11eabb6c0ba18780c19a8da0c31ace671265e3c87fa'
kSigning = 'f4780e2d9f65fa895f9c67b32ce1baf0b0d8a43505a000a1a9e090d414db404d'
```

I am unable to generate the above values in R unfortunately.

I would like to understand what are the mistakes in the R functions.

Here are more details, in case you want to understand where this is coming from (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-other)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Python to R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933400/convert-python-to-r)

Comment: No, it does not. Most of the answers are about how to call R from Python or the opposite. The functions are library dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out.

For the first function it doesn't require *digest* and keep the argument *raw=T*.

```
sign=function(key, msg)
{
  return (hmac(key,msg,"sha256", raw=T))
}
```

The second function is given below with an addition of a line that converts a vector of bytes to a string

```
getSignatureKey=function(key, date_stamp, regionName, serviceName)
{
  kDate = sign(paste0('AWS4' , key), date_stamp)
kRegion = sign(kDate, regionName)
kService = sign(kRegion, serviceName)
kSigning = sign(kService, 'aws4_request')

kSigning=paste(kSigning,collapse="")
return (kSigning)
}
```

For some reason keeping the argument, *raw=F* in the *hmac* function messed up the subsequent signing operations in function 2. Hence keeping *raw=T* and using *paste*  to finally make it a character string.